# How can I add a class for category | link_to

Tags: bigcartel

I am designing my custom bigcartel theme and I need to add a class to a certain part of code that is automatically inserted with the bigcartel api.

I have this code here for submenu links and it works fine:

```
{% for category in categories.active %}
<li>{{ category | link_to }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Now I need to add a specific class to the links that are being creatred, but I don't understand how. I checked the help site, but I am not sure how to do it, as I only need to add a class. On the help site the definition looks like this:

> link_to(item, text, title, id, class, rel)

And the example looks like that:

> {{ category | link_to: 'Tees', 'View tees category', 'tees_category', 'categories' }}

Does anyone have an idea how to add only the class, but not necessarily add all of the other stuff like the title, id, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore the other parameters just by passing '' instead of a value, like so:

```
{% for category in categories.active %}
  <li>{{ category | link_to: '', '', '', 'categories' }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

You can also manually build these links if you want, you don't need to follow the example entirely:

```
{% for category in categories.active %}
  <li><a href="{{ category.url }}" title="{{ category.name }}" id="{{ category.permalink }}">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: perfect. that works like a charm. I tried something similar, but I had spaces between the ' ' so it did not work.